# How to put the 1st element of a list at the end?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have a problem with my linked list. I just want to put the first element to the end but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks for your help

```
typedef struct Element Element_t;
struct Element
{
    int nbr;
    Element_t *next;
};
```

This is my function to put the first element to the end. But that just take the first element and I don't know how to put it at the end.

```
void my_ra(Element_t **l_a)
{
    Element_t *temp;

    if ((*l_a) && (*l_a)->next)
        *l_a = (*l_a)->next;
}
```

The first list is when I do nothing, the second is when I try to put the first element at the end.

```
1 2 9 4 5 $
2 9 4 5 $
```

Comment: Welcome! Please don't post text as linked images - it's even quicker to copy/paste the actual text than a screen shot.

Comment: @Yes What does the symbol $ mean?

Comment: the $ of the list is a \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but if I want to make it just with a simple pointer like

```
Element_t *l_a
```

I try to do this but it doesn't work !

```
void my_ra(Element_t *list)
{
    Element_t *temp1 = list;
    Element_t *temp2 = NULL;

    while (list->next->next != NULL)
        list = list->next;
    temp2 = list->next;
    temp2->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    list->next = temp1;
}
```

that make me the same as before
first list : 1 2 3 4
after compilation : 1

Thx for your help

Comment: You can't post your progress as an answer. Please use the debugger to understand what's happening in each step. Indeed it is good exercise to understand behavior by your own.  You can print the address at each step and cross verify with your assumptions. There is an answer given by expert please try to understand what is being said.

Answer (score 0):

The function can be defined the following way

```
void my_ra(Element_t **l_a)
{
    if ( *l_a != NULL && ( *l_a )->next != NULL )
    {
        Element_t *tmp = *l_a;
        *l_a = ( *l_a )->next;
        
        tmp->next = NULL;

        while ( *l_a != NULL ) l_a = &( *l_a )->next;

        *l_a = tmp;
    }
}
```

This part of the function

```
while ( *l_a != NULL ) l_a = &( *l_a )->next;

*l_a = tmp;
```

can be substituted for this code snippet.

```
Element_t *current = *l_a;

while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;

current->next = tmp;
```

In this case the function will look like

```
void my_ra(Element_t **l_a)
{
    if ( *l_a != NULL && ( *l_a )->next != NULL )
    {
        Element_t *tmp = *l_a;
        *l_a = ( *l_a )->next;
        
        tmp->next = NULL;

        Element_t *current = *l_a;

        while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;

        current->next = tmp;
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Element Element_t;
struct Element
{
    int nbr;
    Element_t *next;
};

int push( Element_t **l_a, int nbr )
{
    Element_t *new_element = ( Element_t * )malloc( sizeof( *new_element ) );
    int success = new_element != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        new_element->nbr = nbr;
        new_element->next = *l_a;
        *l_a = new_element;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( const Element_t *l_a )
{
    for (; l_a != NULL; l_a = l_a->next)
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", l_a->nbr );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

void my_ra( Element_t **l_a )
{
    if (*l_a != NULL && ( *l_a )->next != NULL)
    {
        Element_t *tmp = *l_a;
        *l_a = ( *l_a )->next;

        tmp->next = NULL;

        while (*l_a != NULL) l_a = &( *l_a )->next;

        *l_a = tmp;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    Element_t *l_a = NULL;

    enum { N = 10 };

    for (int i = N; i != 0; i--)
    {
        push( &l_a, i );
    }

    display( l_a );

    do
    {
        my_ra( &l_a );
        display( l_a );
    } while (l_a->nbr != 1);
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> null
3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 -> null
4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> null
8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> null
9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> null
10 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but what does it mean l_a = &( *l_a )->next; pls ?

Comment: @Yes The pointer l_a points to the next data member next.

Comment: `while ( *l_a != NULL ) l_a = &( *l_a )->next;` will exit on `*l_a` with `null` value. `*l_a = tmp;` is assignment on `null` pointer.

Comment: @TruthSeeker You are right. It is what is required. :)

Comment: The last `*l_a = tmp` is wrong. You want `*l_a->next = tmp` (draw it out).

Comment: @AlexReynolds All is correct. What is wrong is your comment.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I'm also finding it crazy, but couldn't understand whats happening in the underneath pointer operation. I was expecting a while loop would exit on `*l_a` is set to `NULL` and assigning value to `*l_a` is UB.  But I was wrong, but not able to figure out how!!![here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/KnrPvzqxn)

Comment: @TruthSeeker The loop deals with data members next of nodes by reference through the pointer l_a that points to pointers next. So when the pointer l_a points to the data member next of the last node dereferencing the pointer you get the direct access  to the data member next of the last node and can change it from NULL to tmp. It is the same as for example to write int x; int *p = &x; *p = 10;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: It's clear. thanks for your patience. Basically *l_a is pointing to the last node's pointer. [DEMO](https://www.godbolt.org/z/75bzrPGxo).

Comment: @TruthSeeker More precisely to the data member next (that is a pointer) of the last node.